# file is not running via Shell_exec in php

Tags: php, shell

my code is as below . this will not help me to run this file run_ques.php via shell_exec

```
$location      = $cron_file_location . "/run_ques.php";
$shell_command = "php {$location} > /dev/null &";
shell_exec($shell_command);
echo $cron_file_location;
echo "test";
echo $shell_command;
die();
```

Comment: Any errors? Expected result? Have you access to `shell_exec` function?

Comment: I think his question is how to work this code.

Comment: Its a php code and not a shell program, instead of using a shell_exec directly call the function inside run_ques.php or write a cron. Since its output is redirect to /dev/null the result is missing, try /var/log instead.